# Не монтируются роуты в React приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

По какой-то причине роут не добавляется в приложение

**component.jsx**

```
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

export default props => (
    <div className="App main-content">
            <Switch>
              {props.admin.routes.length
                ? props.admin.routes.map((route, i) => (
                    <Route
                      exact
                      key={i}
                      path={route.path}
                      component={route.component}
                    />
                  );
                )
                : null}
            </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

**props.admin.routes**

[image: тут все хорошо]

**react devTools**

[image: тут пусто]

Т.е. в пропсах есть данные, но они почему-то не рендерятся. С чем это может быть связано?

В корне приложения есть `BrowserRouter`, с этим все нормально

Comment: что у вас в route.path?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

export default ({ admin: { routes = [] } = {} }) => (
    <div className="App main-content">
        {routes.length ? (
            <Switch>
                {routes.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
                    <Route exact key={i} path={path} component={component} />
                ))}
            </Switch>
        ) : null}
    </div>
);
```

**Возможные** причины проблемы:

1. Не импортируете React
2. `<Switch />` рендерится пустой, в случае когда
   `props.admin.routes.length === false`
3. Частая ошибка - когда в пропсу `component` для `<Route />` передают
   jsx а не саму сущность реакт компонента